# ORM for Compact Framework 3.5 winforms app with external ms sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, compact-framework, or-mapper

I'm building a **.NET CF 3.5 application** that will communicate with an **server based MS SQL server 2005**.

The communication will happen trough the devices's WiFi connection.

I've been looking for a good O/R mapper and am a bit lost. Most sites/people assume that you're going to work with a *local compact database* and not with an *external "normal" SQL server*.

In the past, I've worked with entityspaces (but that seems to be commercial now?) and lately with linq-to-sql.

What good easy to learn & implement O/R mappers run on a .NET CF app with normal MS SQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this a few years ago with .NET 1.1 and [LLBLGen](http://www.llblgen.com) with great success.

Comment: hmmm, is also not free to use. :(

Comment: Nope, but it is well worth the price in my opinion. Give it a try though, the code that gets generated isn't limited in the trial. The designer will expire and you won't be able to regen, but you can continue to use what ever was generated in the past.

Comment: @bob: although in the demo EULA it says that you can't use the generated code after the trial expired ;) I'm not THAT generous, Bob ;)

Comment: Frans, how, HOW do you do it? Do you ever sleep? Do you have clones? How are you everywhere like this and still have time to write LLBLGen, which is awesome product by the way.